# How to set env variables for django test in vscode

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I would like to set env variable for django test in vscode.
These env variables will be different from env variables to be used in django run server.

- I can run a django test case through command line - `python manage.py test`.
- In **Pycharm** I can run a test case by clicking on a green play button right next to the test case. In edit configuration I can set env variable.

But in vscode I am unable to run a particular test case. I dont see any play button next to test class name.
I am also unable to set env variables that would be used in a test case.

One way to set env variables is through terminal before running vs code from the terminal. But that is not flexible enough.

Answer (score 0):

Install `python` extension.
You wont get a green `run/play`  button next to each test case like we do in pycharm. But we can run any particular test using following files. 2 options will show up on top left corner after you do following:
Create following 2 files in your project. you may also add these files to .gitignore :

- .vscode/launch.json

  ```
  {
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [

       {
           "name": "Django server",
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
           "args": [
               "runserver"
           ],
           "django": true,
           "justMyCode": true,
           "env": {
               "ALLOWED_HOSTS": "*",
           }
       },
       {
           "name": "Django test",
           "type": "python",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py", 
           "args": [
               "test",
               "app_name.api.tests.test_x.test_t.TestXYZ"
           ],
           "django": true,
           "justMyCode": true,
           "env": {
               "ALLOWED_HOSTS": "*",
           }
       }
   ]
  ```

  }
- .vscode/settings.json

  ```
  {
   "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
   "python.linting.enabled": true,
   "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
       "-v",
       "-s",
       ".",
       "-p",
       "test_*.py"
   ],
   "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
   "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
  }
  ```